# Session Timeout - how to force it for testing

Tags: php

I wonder how can I force session timeout so I can test it, without waiting 15 minutes after logging in :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the session timeout in your code like this:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $timeoutInSeconds);
```